# Debian installer can't see wi-fi

Tags: debian

I'm installing Debian 10.8.0-amd64 on a desktop. The process is OK, but the installer cannot see my wi-fi network. I can overcome this by plugging an Android device and sharing the connection by tethering.

But, Debian installer is the only one that I noticed this issue. Ubuntu(ish) always recognize my network properly and so does Arch, but in this case I need to change the regulatory domain after rebooting).

My network is on channel 13 (2472 MHz).

I tried 2 ISOs:

- Official net install: https://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/current/amd64/iso-cd/debian-10.8.0-amd64-netinst.iso
- Non-free firmware net install: https://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-cd/

Since the official ISO asked for a non-free firmware (`rtl_nic/rtl8168h-2.fw`), I tried the unnoficial ISO with non-free firmware, but the problem persists. Also, the first installer recognize other networks.

I also noticed that there is a file in the installer (`/sys/module/cfg80211/parameters/ieee20811_regdom`) which content is "00", I tried to change it to "BR" but the file isn't writeable.

What am I missing here? There is a way to change it before burning the iso?

Answer (score 0):

The `/sys` directory tree is a virtual `sysfs` filesystem, which is not actually stored on disk at all. Anything you read from there is a real-time presentation of the kernel's internal state; anything writeable there will change the respective kernel or module status in real time.

If you need to change the wireless regulatory domain (`ieee80211_regdom`) manually just once, use the proper command: `iw reg set BR`. If you find you'll always need to specify the country code, the configuration files of `wpa_supplicant` or `hostapd` have a place for it.

The `ieee80211_regdom` is an old kernel module parameter (used before kernel version 2.6.27 and now deprecated) which has only very few valid settings: `US`, `JP` and `EU`. The modern wireless code uses the old parameter only as a very general hint on which frequencies it might be worthwhile to listen for, and/or safe to actively probe for wireless networks (without making e.g. military radar operators unhappy...).

In theory, if the WiFi access point is correctly configured, its network announcement will include the country/frequency region code, which should be used by the clients to auto-detect the region code.

In practice, this mechanism does not always work perfectly and with some wireless adapters in some countries, the system administrator needs to supply the country code. This is especially likely to happen if the only available wireless network is on a channel which is only legal to use in specific parts of the world (i.e. channel 13).

Comment: Thank you for the reply! This is the case here. The network is configured by the provider and I don't have a router here to change the frequency of the signal. I tried to change the domain with `iw reg set`, just like I usually do once the system is installed, but `iw` isn't available in the image.